# Maximum interval for differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The exercise says as follows:

Find the maximum interval of solution of $$y'=\frac{y^3}{1+y^2}e^x+x^2 \cos y, y(0)=y_0$$
I don't even know how to approach this problem. I'm aware of the maximize $a'$ method but I'm not able to reach anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is typically an exercise. Please share what you have been doing first.

Comment: What conditions there are for the existence of solutions to differential equations?

Comment: I know there exists a solution and it is unique by Cauchy-Peano and Picard. I wanna find the maximum interval

Comment: Under what conditions a solution is maximally defined?

Comment: You should have learned some further theorems after the existence theory. For instance the Grönwall lemma in some version. Or conditions for boundedness of solutions over bounded or unbounded intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ f(x,y)=\frac{y^3}{1+y^2}e^x+x^2 \cos y. $$
Note
$$ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{y^2(y^2+3)}{(1+y^2)^2}e^x-x^2 \sin y$$
is bounded in $[-a,a]\times[y_0-\delta,y_0+\delta]$ for any $a>0$ and $\delta>0$ and hence there is $b>0$ such that $y'=f(x,y),y(0)=y_0$ has a solution $y(x)$ for $x\in[0,b)$. Extend the solution $y(x)$ to the maximal interval, still written as $[0,b)$. Now show $b=\infty$. Otherwise if $b<\infty$, then one would have
$$ \lim_{x\to b^-}|y(x)|=\infty. \tag1$$
On the other hand, integrating the equation gives
$$ y(x)=y(0)+\int_0^x\bigg[\frac{y^3(t)}{1+y^2(t)}e^t+t^2 \cos y(t)\bigg]dt$$
from which one has
$$ |y(x)|\le|y(0)|+\int_0^x\bigg[|y(t)|e^t+t^2\bigg]dt\le\bigg[|y(0)|+\frac{x^3}3\bigg]+\int_0^xe^t|y(t)|dt. $$
By Gronwall's inequality for integral form, one has
$$ |y(x)|\le \bigg[|y(0)|+\frac{x^3}3\bigg]\exp\bigg[\int_0^xe^tdt\bigg]=\bigg[|y(0)|+\frac{x^3}3\bigg]\exp\bigg[e^x-1\bigg] \tag2$$
Letting $x\to b^-$ in (2) gives
$$ \lim_{x\to b^-}|y(x)|<\infty $$
which is against (1).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the maximal interval $I$ of the solution is bounded above and therefore that the solution only exists on the right in $[0, a)$ with $ a \gt 0$.

With easy inequalities, we get

$$\lvert y^\prime(x) \lvert \le \lvert y(x) \lvert e^a +a^2$$ for $x \in [0, a)$.

$y^\prime$ vanishes at most a finite number of times in $[0,a)$ as otherwise, $y$ would be the always vanishing map and the maximal interval unbounded in contradiction with our hypothesis.

But then applying [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) and the inequality $\frac{d}{dx}\lvert y(x) \rvert \le \lvert y^\prime(x) \lvert$, you get that $y$ is bounded in $[0,a)$ and can be extended beyond $a$. A contradiction.